# Trying to make a list case insensitive in discord.py (python)

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a bad word filter for a bot that I am making for my friend's server, but, the list is case sensitive. How do I fix this?

> ```
> @client.event
> async def on_message(message):
>    author = message.author
>     content = message.content
>     channel = message.channel
>     log = client.get_channel(log channel)
>     bad_words=["bad","word","yellow"]
>     if any(bad_word in content for bad_word in bad_words):
>         embed = discord.Embed(title="Bad word detected!", color=discord.Color.red())
>         embed.add_field(name=f"{author.display_name}, you have said a forbidden word!", value="You 
>         have been sent to Jail!")
>         embed2 = discord.Embed(title=f"Bad word sent by {author} in #{channel}.", 
>         color=discord.Color.red())
>         embed2.add_field(name="They said:", value=f"{author.display_name}: {content}")
>         await message.delete()
>         await author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(author.guild.roles, name="jail"))
>         await channel.send(embed=embed)
>         await log.send(embed=embed2)
>     await client.process_commands(message)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the content lowercase before you check with it

```
content = message.content.lower()
```